# While loop in C, with non-executed condition

Tags: c, while-loop

I keep coming across the following pattern in my C code:

```
_Bool executed = 0;
while (condition) {
   executed = 1;
   ...
}
if (!executed) {
   ...
}
```

Is there a better way to construct this?

Ideally:

```
while (condition) {
   executed = 1;
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

(A `while`/`else` loop, but not with Python's semantics.  The `else` should be only executed if the while condition was immediately false.)

Comment: Why change? it's working and looking fine logic...

Comment: You're confusing `while` with `if`.

Comment: @Barmar no he is not. The codition might be changing in the while. And in case he only wants to execute the next block if 0 while loop iterations happened.

Comment: @TonyTannous I mean that you can only have `else` with `if`, you can't use it with `while`.

Comment: @Barmar ah now I get what you mean :)

Comment: Python allows `else` with loops, but as he says it has different semantics; it executes whenever the loop ends normally rather than from `break`.

Comment: To the OP: please be a bit more specific in your example `...` is not actual code. Depending on the loop body, different patterns (involving break/continue/return/goto) could be used.

Comment: @wildplasser I had the same thought, but maybe OP wants a generic solution/simplification.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: It is too vague, and there is no general *solution*. Normally, the loop has some other effects (for instance: setting variables), which can be used instead of the indicator variable.

Comment: @klutt Read the last sentence carefully. OP wants the test of `!executed` only if the `while` loop wasn´t executed. With its actual code, the check is done regardless whether the while loop was executed at least once or not.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Maybe so, but I still cannot see what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems

```
_Bool executed = 0;
while (condition) {
   executed = 1;
   ...
}
if (!executed) {
   ...
}
```

If `condition` has side effects, it can be changed with

```
if (condition) {
    do 
    {

    } while(condition);
} else {

}
```

But if you insist only using a `while`, and not a `do... while` then your penalty is evaluating `condition` again.

```
if (condition) {
    while(condition)
    {

    }
} else {

}
```

Comment: @Fredrik In your opinion maybe. For me it's explicit that the else is fired when `condition` is **immediately** false. I don't have to track the logic of `executed`

Comment: I don´t understand them. It´s exactly what OP is looking for. I had given the same answer. +1

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio understand who and what :) ?

Comment: @TonyTannous The ones who ain´t see this answer to the question. Maybe it can have some issues because it is not case-specific. But to view it from a generic point, this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: You're first change is the better.  It's a pity that the condition needs to be repeated.

Comment: @fadedbee added a note for OP.

Comment: @TonyTannous fadedbee is OP.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio too much comments to follow :)

Comment: @TonyTannous :-)